# PHP Tokens - finding user defined constants

Tags: php, constants, token

got a reall head scratcher. Im trying to make a PHP obfuscator  ( http://www.actwebdesigns.co.uk/web-design-blog/actobfuscator-free-open-source-php-obfuscator/ )

I've hit a little problem tho. I cant find a guaranteed way of finding a user defined constant.

some of my the token_name()'s return as T_STRING and others as T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, which with my code as it is does not change all constantss as shown below;

```
 <?php
//ACTObfuscator - Created by ACT Web Designs
//http://www.actwebdesigns.co.uk
?>
<?php
 @define("V566B1DF8B3B32D1", false); if( V566B1DF8B3B32D1 ) { define('DB_USERNAME', "wefghgfh"); define('DB_PASSWORD', "mulfghgfh"); define('DB_SERVER', "gfhgst"); define("V2FC1E4F930A251A", "webfghgfh"); define("VDA9E0DAA31346F8", "<+ site_name +>"); define("V4424E58002D8BE7", "actvbiz.co.uk"); define("VBE72B58F4FE19A6", '<img src="./?0000=jpg&0001=0001&0002=pic" width="277" style="position:relative; z-index:5; background:url(./?0000=png&0001=shade&0002=pic) bottom repeat-x;" height="167" alt="ACTvBiz Logo" />' ); define("V7052A961BF53D55", "http://www.actvbiz.co.uk"); define("V692CD2C3D40F692", "support@activbiz.co.uk"); define("VDC5565EDE9405AA", "nnn_accounts"); }else{ header("location: http://www.actvbiz.co.uk"); exit; } ?>
```

(ignore the <+ foobar +> as thats for something else)

any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Normally `define` should be a `T_STRING`. Futhermore: Please don't use `token_name($token[0]) == 'T_STRING'` use `$token[0] == T_STRING` instead. That's why PHP defined whose constants... Please furthermore use `file_get_constants` instead of `implode` ing a `file()`. Can you point out where in your obfuscator code you are registering the constants? Can't find it.

Comment: $token[0] returns a numeric value which token_name converts to a Parser Token, i.e. 'T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING'

Comment: `}elseif( is_int($token[0]) && token_name($token[0]) == 'T_STRING' && preg_match( "#^[A-Z_]+$#", $token[1] ) ) {  `

Comment: Yes, $token[0] indeed is a numeric value. And this numeric value is `T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING` (a constant that PHP defines.) No need to use `token_name`. I don't get why your code should recognize `define`. There isn't the string `define` in that code, actually.

Answer (score 0):

How I would find user defined constants (using whose with `define`, not the `const` ones):

```
foreach (token_get_all($source) as $token) {
    if (!is_array($token)) continue;
    list($id, $content) = $token;
    if ($id == T_STRING && $content == 'define') {
        // and now extract the constant name!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I realise what the problem is... throughout the whole of my documents I have removed ( lets say ) DOMAIN constant and is only left with DEFINE('DOMAIN'); So in theory, as it is not used anywhere, it has no need to be 'changed'. But to over come this, and only alter the 'defined' constants and not what 'appears' ( no proof of it being defined ) to be a constant, I wrote this:

```
foreach( $tokens as $key => $packet ) {
    $x = $key + 1;
    if( is_array( $packet ) && $packet[0] == T_STRING && $packet[1] == 'define' ) {
        while( true ) {
            if( is_array( $tokens[$x] ) && $tokens[$x][0] == T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING ) {
                $constants[] = str_replace( array("\s", "'", '"'), '', $tokens[$x][1] );
                break;  
            }
            $x++;
        }
    }
}
```

This will only add value as a constant if in the defined() function. Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => VIA_SITE
    [1] => DB_USERNAME
    [2] => DB_PASSWORD
    [3] => DB_SERVER
    [4] => DB_NAME
    [5] => SITE_NAME
    [6] => PROFILE_URL
    [7] => _LOGO
    [8] => DOMAIN
    [9] => SUPPORT_EMAIL
    [10] => ACCOUNT_TABLE
)
```

Comment: I guess in a way the first way of getting the define name shows whether or not it is use throughout the scripts.

Answer (score -1):

Please format your code, this way it's not very readable.

You can check if a constant is defined by that very function: [defined](http://php.net/manual/en/function.defined.php).

```
if (defined('V566B1DF8B3B32D1')) {
}
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: the code above is what is outputted from my code ( displayed in the link ) V566B1DF8B3B32D1 has been altered due to it's token name is returning correctly. there are some tho returning as T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, which is incorrect anyone with anyideas why??
`Please format your code, this way it's not very readable. ` Thats the idea ;-)